# Responsive images for 3 different types of screens : Is this a good design? (pic inside)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

[image]

Above image is a wireframe layout of my portfolio website.
The navbar is at the bottom while the 2 images fill the remaining screen.
The left and right picture will be contained in their own DIV (something like left picture DIV width set to 65% and right one set to 35%)

Based on this, I guess I need to prepare 3 different sets of images, one for large screens, one for mobile portrait and one for mobile landscape?

At first I was thinking just 2 sets would be enough, as large screens and mobile landscape can share the images, but then, some mobile landscape views (depending on device) have a very wide width to short height ratio, so the images won't look that good.

Any advice would be greatly welcomed!
Tks!

Comment: It looks good enough. but this is wrong place to ask for feedback of wireframe design :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt go this way..
You have to keep in mind that maybe the user uses the landscape mode because he want to see things bigger. With your design he wouldnt see much more.
I would stick to the design of the iphone to let the images be under each other.

Comment: Tks! However, the 2 pictures will be in a slider and I don't want any scrollbars, though. I intend the look to be like a single page app.